# Cast dialog has a solid white bar near the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, chromecast

I am working on a Cast app and I see this extra white strip at the bottom of the screen when the Cast dialog is launched. It's only visible when there is an existing session, it doesn't show with the the device selector.

[image]

Comment: Okay, So what exactly you want.? And please provide your all xmls and java files related to it or else we will not be able to understand your code better.

Comment: @UmangBurman This dialog is managed by android, there is no custom XML or code.

Comment: Okay, So what exactly are you looking for ?